# How do I set IE8 default start-up arguments?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, windows-registry

I want to set IE to start with arguments every time  launch it **or he get invoked by an another process.**

The argument is **-nomerge**

Comment: I think you're stuck with the old trick of a shortcut.

Comment: not really, it work fine that way, i just want to make it the default when I start iexplorer.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well-behaved programs will use `ShellExecute` / `ShellExecuteEx` to launch URLs rather than executing `iexplore.exe` directly (so that they launch whatever browser you've set as default). Therefore, you could search the registry for occurrences of `iexplore.exe`, and (you'll have to use your judgement here, I'm not going to list all cases) where it is referring to an executable path (but not to fetch its icon), add the argument you want. You'll also have to add the argument to all shortcuts which point to `iexplore.exe`, which there shouldn't be too many of - on the start menu and quick launch bar; maybe on the desktop.

Comment: okay i've posted the answer

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a good solution for your question which doesn't involve monkeying with
iexplore.exe.

I haven't test the solution offered below (which frankly I find a bit extreme even if it might answer your post):

1. Rename `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` as `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.orig.exe`.
2. Open notepad, paste this in, and save it as `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.bat`

   @echo off
   "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.orig.exe" -nomerge %*
3. Using a batch file compiler, such as [Quick Batch File Compiler](http://www.battoexe.com/) or [Batch File Compiler Professional](http://www.bdargo.com/), compile `iexplore.bat` to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

With this solution, "iexplore.orig.exe -nomerge" will run whenever `iexplore.exe` is invoked.

Some notes:

1. You will need to repeat this procedure whenever Windows Update replaces iexplore.exe.
2. You might need to carry out this procedure while booted in Safe mode.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried that, and it seems to me, that IE is checking whether name of its executable was changed and if it was, it won't execute.

Comment: @sYnfo: This approach doesn't work then for IE8. These guys are too smart for us.

Comment: Well, I looked at disassembly and it looks nice & clean, maybe I (Or someone more skilled) would be able to circumvent that "protection". Although this solution probably wouldn't survive updates.

Comment: Im not getting any valid answers

Comment: You can't monkey too much with IE. Microsoft has done its best to protect this program which used to be the front door for viruses. I and others in this forum have tried to challenge Microsoft and failed. There is no way to do it except to disassemble IE and change its programming, which will require a quite disproportionate effort.

Answer (score 2):

Browse to this path 
`HKEY_CURRENT _USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` and set `SessionMerging` to 0

or Newer OSs:
`HKEY_CURRENT _USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` and set `FrameMerging` to 0.

The registry file would look something like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"SessionMerging"=dword:00000000
"FrameMerging"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new registry setting for IE8 that appears to do the same thing as `-nomerge`. The new IE8 behavior that `-nomerge` defeats is a result of the process model change, and you can undo that with a registry setting. Create a `DWORD` value called `TabProcGrowth` in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
```

The default setting is `<absent>`, you should first try `0` which will use the IE7-style process model. If that does what you want, then also try `1` which will give you some of the new features. Numbers greater than `1` may also be useful. [More info is here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx)

Certainly you could replace `iexplore.exe` with `iexplore.cmd` or even a small program that executed the real `iexplore.exe` that you have hidden off somewhere, with new arguments. This poses a few problem, as Windows itself will clobber iexplore.exe with new versions and various protection mechanisms that come and go. I would definitely try the registry key first.

Comment: TabProcGrowth permit launching new tabs under a new iexplore.exe process. for my case, Im launching new processes, -nomerge allow iexplore.exe instances to run each in its own separate session.

Comment: Right, but the changes are related. It might be worth a try...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fiddling with shareware, just use a compiled language and make a second binary. Name `iexplore.exe` to `iexplore2.exe`, drop this in the directory along with it, and away you go:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<shellapi.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                     int nShowCmd)
{
    ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,"iexplore2.exe","-nomerge",NULL,SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled a binary for you [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/299725053/iexplore.zip). If you don't trust it, you can compile the above source yourself with any up to date Windows compatible C++ compiler.

As noted previously, a Windows update for IE will probably mess this up. So keep a copy of this binary elsewhere.

Comment: your solution don't differ from the .bat one, ans still not valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be the same as turning on the option to open links in a new window?  The setting can be found on Tools->Internet Options->General Tab->Tabs->Settings:

[image]

Comment: While your solution will open IE8 links in a new window, it does not open those windows with new "sessions". You would still want to use the modified shortcut or registry method to disable Frame Merging.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start it from a batch file?

```
iexplore.exe -nomerge
```

Comment: yes , no problems ... why ?

Comment: My mistake. I didn't see the line where you wanted anything that calls IE to get -nomerge. That was just an alternative to you launching it from a shortcut.